# Is it possible that a seekbar and listview be in a layout.xml in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to use a seekbar and listview in a layout.xml and an Activity in android. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes is it possible, see the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="This is your seek bar"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="This is your List View"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```